# Problems installing GeoIP using Cloud9 (Windows 10)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, geoip, cloud9

I'm trying to set up a cloud-based IDE (on a Windows machine) to test and update a Ruby project on GitHub. I'm struggled with installing all the required parts.

'bundle install' works to a point, then it fails here:

```
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... yes
checking for GeoIP_record_by_ipnum() in -lGeoIP... no
you must have geoip c library installed!
.
.
An error occurred while installing geoip-c (0.9.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install geoip-c -v '0.9.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

All of these fail:

```
gem install geoip-c
gem install geoip-c -v '0.9.1'
gem install geoip-c -- --with-geoip-dir=/opt/GeoIP
```

with this error message:

```
ERROR:  Error installing geoip-c:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/geoip-c-0.9.1/ext/geoip
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170628-2852-11bgk28.rb extconf.rb
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... yes
checking for GeoIP_record_by_ipnum() in -lGeoIP... no
you must have geoip c library installed!
```

Been scratching my brain for a couple of days now - any help gratefully appreciated.

Comment: did you read this post ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748168/error-installing-geoip-city-gem#2754397

Comment: Yes, I get the same error: `checking for GeoIP_record_by_ipnum() in -lGeoIP... no \n you must have geoip c library installed!`

Comment: in that post they run that `gem install geoip_city -- --with-geoip-dir=/opt/GeoIP` with the `env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"` so that specifies if the system is 64 bit.. also they run the command as system user with `sudo` (system user do)

Answer (score 1):

this are the install instructions from the geoip gem.
You need to perform this on the Cloud9 server, not on your local windows 10 machine.

Your application is running on a Linux Server hosted by cloud9, you need to access that server terminal (the black and white window) so that you can install and configure some utilities on the Linux host.

This shows how to open the terminal on Cloud9
https://docs.c9.io/docs/terminal

This are the installation instructions for geoip, you need to follow those for linux, if you are running on cloud9 a linux server.

https://github.com/mtodd/geoip#install

So maybe this is just not compatible with Windows.

> Install
>
> Some variation of the following should work.
>
> Install the GeoCity C library. You can get it from MaxMind. For
>   example, I like to install mine in /opt/GeoIP, so I do this:
>
> tar -zxvf GeoIP-1.4.3.tar.gz cd GeoIP-1.4.3 ./configure
>   --prefix=/opt/GeoIP make && sudo make install
>
> On Mac OS X, you can install using
>   [homebrew](http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew):
>
> ```
> brew install geoip
> ```
>
> Linux platforms utilizing Apt have several packages available:
>
> ```
> geoip-bin
> geoip-database
> libgeoip-dev Now install the geoip gem
> ```
>
> gem install geoip-c -- --with-geoip-dir=/opt/GeoIP
>
> Alternatively, if you installed libgeoip using homebrew:
>
> ```
> gem install geoip-c Download the GeoLite City database file in binary format at http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity Maybe this
> ```
>
> direct link will work. I put this file in
>
> /opt/GeoIP/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
>
> If you installed libgeoip using homebrew then put it in:
>
> ```
> /usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
> ```
>
> If you are a paying customer, you will download the files required
>   below:
>
> [MaxMind Customer
>   Downloads](http://www.maxmind.com/app/download_files)
>
> You will want to get the City Rev1 data file and Organization files
>   at minimum. Use it!
>
> See above for usage details.
>
> Hints
>
> Might need to set
>
> export ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386"
>
> to be able to compile the gem.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386" gem install geoip-c -- --with-geoip-dir=/opt/GeoIP You might find this shell script helpful to install the C library.
> ```